# Divisão de tabelas com Count e Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou elaborando uma consulta onde tenho algumas somas e contagens e, em algumas partes, preciso fazer uma divisão em uma tabela que somei ou fiz a contagem, por exemplo:

```
COUNT(M.ID_MAILING),
SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Preciso fazer uma divisão entre essas duas operações, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(M.ID_MAILING))
```

(também tentei sem o "()" a mais), mas a coluna sempre retorna "0".

O que pode estar faltando? O AVG creio que não me sirva, pois ele trás a média da tabela e, nesse caso, as operações estão tratando tabelas diferentes.

Estou utilizando o SQL Server Management Studio.

Segue estrutura das tabelas:

Tabela: Mailing

[image: Tabela: Mailing]

Tabela: Status (IS_APPROACH)
[image: Tabela: Status (IS_APPROACH)]

**Query completa:**

```
    SET LANGUAGE 'ENGLISH'

SELECT
    C.NM_CAMPAIGN AS 'Campanha',
    COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS 'Base Recebida',
    SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Abordagem',
    SUM(CASE WHEN SS.ID_STATUS IN ('1002','1004','1019','1079','1084','1102','1138','1139','1140','1141','1142','1143','1144','1145','1150','1154') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Promessas de Pagamento',
    SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS '% Mailing Abordado',
    SUM(CASE WHEN SS.ID_STATUS_GROUP IN (17,18,19,20,22,23,25,26,30,31) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Contato Efetivo',
FROM MAILING M
    JOIN CAMPAIGN C         ON C.ID_CAMPAIGN = M.ID_CAMPAIGN
    JOIN STATUS SS          ON SS.ID_STATUS = M.ID_STATUS
GROUP BY C.NM_CAMPAIGN
```

Comment: O que retorna o SUM e COUNT separados ?

Comment: @Motta valores inteiros, como 1036 e 301 (primeiros resultados dessas colunas).

Comment: @devin se puder editar a pergunta e colocar como é a estrutura das suas tabelas fazendo um favor, acho que ajudaria. Tentei simular aqui e não tive nenhum problema

Comment: a estrutura das tabelas e a query completa

Comment: Editei com as tabelas e a query completa, @LeandroSimões@RovannLinhalis

Comment: @devin Creio que o problema seja que ao dividir, você está obtendo valores quebrados, por exemplo: `1036 / 301 = 3,44186046...` sendo assim, você tem que fazer um `CAST` dos valores para `DECIMAL`, assim: `(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS DECIMAL))  AS '% Mailing Abordado'`

Faça o teste, se for isso mesmo eu crio uma resposta aqui.

Comment: @LeandroSimões funcionou!! Outra coisa, o resultado ficou  "0.2905405405405405405", por exemplo, consigo já deixar isso em %?

Comment: @devin Tenta fazer `CAST(((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS DECIMAL)) * 100) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS '% Mailing Abordado'`.

Caso queira formatado já em string seria: `REPLACE(CAST(CAST(((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS DECIMAL)) * 100) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS VARCHAR) + ' %', '.', ',') AS '% Mailing Abordado'`

Comment: @devin Criei uma resposta, se puder dar upvote pra ajudar eu agradeço! Espero ter ajudado! Precisar estou a disposição. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a divisão está retornando um valor quebrado, e o SQL não faz a conversão para DECIMAL automaticamente, sendo assim, você precisa converter os valores desta forma:

```
CAST(((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS DECIMAL)) * 100) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS '% Mailing Abordado'
```

Desta forma já retorna o valor em percentual já formatado com duas casas decimais. Caso queira já em string, formatado para percentual, faça:

```
REPLACE(CAST(CAST(((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.IS_APPROACH = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(COUNT(M.ID_MAILING) AS DECIMAL)) * 100) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS VARCHAR) + ' %', '.', ',') AS '% Mailing Abordado'
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!